# Number of ways to remove items from box

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I encountered the following algorithmic question which has strict constraints on runtime (<10s and no large memory footprint) and I am stumped. My approach fails half the test cases.

**Question**

A box contains a number of items that can only br removed 1 at a time or 3 at a time.

How many ways can the box be emptied? the answer can be very large so return it as modulo of 10^9+7.

for example,there are n=7 items initially.They can be removed nine ways,as follows:

```
1.(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
2.(1.1.1.1.3)
3.(1,1,1,3,1)
4.(1,1,3,1,1)
5.(1,3,1,1,1)
6.(3,1,1,1,1)
7.(1,3,3)
8.(3,1,3)
9.(3,3,1)
```

So the function should return 9.

Function Description:
Your function must take in a parameter, `n` for the number of items, and return an integer which denotes the number of ways to empty the box.

Constraints: `1<=n<=10^8`

Sample cases :

```
Input: 1
Sample OutPut: 1
Explanation: There is only 1 way to remove 1 item. Answer=(1%1000000007)=1

Input: 7
Sample OutPut: 9
There is only 9 ways to remove 7 items
```

**My Approach**

This leads to a standard recurrence relation where `f(n) = f(n-3) + f(n-1)` for n > 2, so i did it as follows

```
def memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n):
    if n not in dic:
        dic[n] = memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n-3) + memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n-1)
    return dic[n]

def numberOfWays(n):
    # Write your code here
    memoize = {1:1,2:1,3:2}
    import math
    ans = memoized_number_of_ways(memoize,n)
    return ans % (math.pow(10,9) + 7)
```

However this fails on any case where `n > 10**2`. How can you do this problem while accomodating `n` up to `10^8` and in less than 10s with not much memory?

Comment: What does "fail" for n>100 mean? Goal should btw be O(log n) time and O(1) space, and you're on the right track.

Comment: Hello, i mentioned it in the first line - fails for memory and runtime. sorry for being unclear! @KellyBundy

Comment: So n=101 takes too much memory or time? I don't believe that.

Comment: For `n = 10**3`  its `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` . For an alternate DP method which i didnt list down here, it gets memoryerror and restarts kernel. @KellyBundy

Comment: Recursion error at 1000 is normal, yes. If it does fail at 101, then probably because you get wrong results due to using floats.

Comment: If you *could* calculate the answer first without the modulus and only apply the modulus after that, the original answer would *not* be very large, so it would not make sense to require the answer modulo something.

Comment: In Python you can write 10**9 as, (surprise!) `10**9`, which is an integer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: that's not true in Python, in which integers are bignums. In fact, an integer can represent a number *much* larger than a float. `10**1000` produces the expected result. `math.pow(10, 1000)` generates an `OverflowError`. (Floats are often faster, though, if you can tolerate the imprecision.)

Comment: @rici The answer for `10^8` elements without the modulus has about 15 million decimal digits, which is rather a lot. You may or may not be able to come up with a solution that computes it within given space and time constraints. If I were to run this contest, I would make sure you can't do that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: That's correct. So I guess it depends on your definition of "very large".

Comment: (FWIW: My laptop can multiply two 7.5-million-digit numbers in 10s, using about 6MB. It's a lot but is it really unreasonable? Just asking.)

Comment: @rici Did you do that with `int`? Try `decimal`, should be faster.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. How did you get 15 million? I estimate 16.6 million, so if I'm not mistaken, you're using some estimation way as well?

Comment: @Kelly: Sure, but it's no longer exact.

Comment: @rici I would hazard a guess that this challenge is not about who has the best laptop. The memory and time constraints are set in the automatic judge, and I sure hope they are set in such a way that submissions by people who don't know how to avoid bignum arithmetic will fail.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes 16.6 million is a better estimation, I just lowballed it.

Comment: @rici Of course I mean when you configure it to be exact, as shown in the last question/answer at the bottom of its documentation page.

Comment: @rici I.e., like [this](https://tio.run/##NU/LbsMgELzzFXszRG5E6@bRSD5UqQ85JKp66s0iGCe09WKtqZR@vQvG4cDs7gw7TP/nrw6LbU/j2JLroDHaduoHbNc78rBg05QUNgHmob46q82QKG87cydizdhgvHbozc3z/Yw9GV0eXz/r949qn0PVqdvUVuGKrcXyeDiF9nASgrHGtEDYcCw39UrKWkopdgzCaezF@gHK@x949vhUPK/Wm@1LlsN3iWKSkfG/hPCWwvAsW345izy9jg4qh3PYEk1EnoCx1hHUYDHGvRhezJ5eBmWMxtNyBQs4T1VPFj1PFDwEoRjHfw). Takes about two seconds there and your laptop seems about twice as fast, so should take you about 1 second.

Comment: @kelly: Yeah, about 1.5 seconds. I was just doing exactly that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Apparently, it's 16,600,693 digits. Took about a minute using Kelly's suggestion and a not very well optimised binary exponentiation. (Yes, outside of OP's time limit.)

Comment: @rici I wonder what solution the problem setter had in mind when they set the 10 s limit. The optimal solution should take a split second, and other solutions seem too slow for the limit. I don't see a middle ground solution that would take between 1 and 10 seconds.

Comment: @rici Heh, found such a middle ground solution after all, see my answer. Perhaps even the unoptimized version takes less than 10 s on your machine?

Comment: @kelly: Just barely, 9.6s. Meanwhile, I managed to get the binary recursion down to 14.5s. Probably could ease a few more cycles by making it iterative. (That's for the precise value, not the modulus.)

Comment: @rici Do you think recursive vs iterative makes a noticeable difference for yours? I imagine almost all your time is spent in very few but very large multiplications. In any case I hope you'll share it :-)

Comment: No, it turns out that it doesn't. I thought the order of multiplications in the iterative solution would be more efficient, but I wasn't thinking clearly; in the recursive solution, no extra multiplication is actually needed for one-bits (it's just an addition), whereas the iterative solution does an extra multiply for every one-bit. So it's generally slower. (That won't apply to a modulo solution, where the recursion overhead is probably more noticeable.) But I did get it down to just under 10 seconds on my machine, so that's something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three solutions, fastest takes about 31 μs for n=10<sup>8</sup> on tio.run (which has medium-fast computers).

A matrix power solution like described by advocateofnone that takes about 1 millisecond ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHLasQgFN37FXdT0IwNmZlFH9DFLLMo@YAQxGlMK8QHakrm61OtQkO7qavDedxzVXsLH0aft00qa1wAvSh7A@5BWzQ5oyBIJaCICSP0NnPv4dWMrQ7PCOIZxQSMSS0DY9iLeaKwkiylk5h6hRdY4Q7wsamqJzjAA9ll@TjGKKdw3eWcCIvTpQnzOOIA13rd59Qy/ydX/c754Mqqf3NRw3llglCyezN/CqyLs4sXKaObPLL9YY6ZuURG21rx4OSK@76jLe0GChFEmED7DYZsL8X4UlWa9Cd6GhCajAMGUoPj@l3gc2kPTRyd/gHnqHUy1uYN08s@ElpkuI9msm1f)):

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

class ModInt:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x % (10**9 + 7)
    def __add__(a, b):
        return ModInt(a.x + b.x)
    def __mul__(a, b):
        return ModInt(a.x * b.x)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

def solve(n):
    O = ModInt(0)
    I = ModInt(1)
    A = np.matrix([[O,I,O], [O,O,I], [I,O,I]])
    return (A**n)[2,2]

for _ in range(3):
    t0 = time()
    print(solve(10**8), time() - t0)
```

Output (result and time in seconds for n=10<sup>8</sup>, three attempts):

```
109786077 0.0010712146759033203
109786077 0.0010180473327636719
109786077 0.0009677410125732422
```

Another, taking about 0.5 milliseconds ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLbsMgELzzFXOJhCltbHLoQ8oh32FZlaXgBiksaEOa5utdwFZbdS/Mzg6j2Y33dAq0m2fnY@AEuvp4x3gBRTFx8EjOW6zDgoU42gmXcP60kpo3gVwH7LP@yY@J3Zfs@1Z3uh00MsiwgK6CoanyGG6W85eudj4cC26VesUDnit3O7mzBS3updwEwgbml/lrtLwq59gUux9NyXVQyvyjCdvtHqb2bNOVaXHojTaDEFNgvMMReKQPK3frkqnNbuUCct2CHSW5HKKkf2n0OsZjFjfz/A0)):

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

def solve(n):
    A = np.matrix([[0,1,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,1]])
    power = 1
    mod = 10**9 + 7
    while n:
        if n % 2:
            power = power * A % mod
        A = A**2 % mod
        n //= 2
    return power[2,2]

for _ in range(3):
    t0 = time()
    print(solve(10**8), time() - t0)
```

One based on @rici's solution in the comments, takes about 31 μs ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFNboMwEIX3PsXbRBjXTSCR2jQSC/JzjsqASZFigxynUu/WM/RKdExSJ52Fjb55fsPMDF/@o7er9eDGsXW9ge@M7jw6M/TOw@lBK89Yo1uc@9On5jbdMFAYFMgzId7whNeJBI2q6qgI0bWwKApkdxTCaX9xFplELpHFlJKoJGpynnywWGCZxmwTOFWrI9FEKiJNJCWRpVAi0FrclbuJV6IOanHXHyZei4a4FjryPfGS2C6SLZEDnrH/39sMy/@tlRJbOdULl3zQ35ouZ4Yk4djNDHtInC@GX@eXkq1hzN5GvGaD66znfwtIWds7vKOzcMoeNV/dJu7pgeksv26Nn5SpGrWJi5NIjvVcW1WdNE8TCXsxlXZFnmUZ1VwgfExG13rJbJ63@Pk@J/Q/3EMg1y9pOo6/)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def solve(n):
    m = 10**9 + 7
    def abc(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0, 1, 0
        a, b, c = abc(n // 2)
        d = a + c
        e = b + d
        A = 2*a*b + c*c
        C = 2*b*c + d*d
        E = 2*c*d + e*e
        D = A + C
        B = E - D
        if n % 2:
            A, B, C = B, C, D
        return A%m, B%m, C%m
    return sum(abc(n)) % m

n = 10**8
print(solve(n))
for _ in range(3):
    t = min(repeat(lambda: solve(n), 'gc.enable()', number=1000)) / 1000
    print('%.1f μs' % (t * 1e6))
```

Explanation: Looking at the matrix powers from my previous solutions, I noticed they only actually contain five different values, and they're consecutive result numbers from our desired sequence. For example, `A**19` is:

```
[[277 189 406]
 [406 277 595]
 [595 406 872]]
```

I gave them names in increasing order:

```
| b a c |
| c b d |
| d c e |
```

Squaring that matrix results in a matrix for larger n, with entries A/B/C/D/E. And if you square the above matrix, you'll find the relationships `A = 2*a*b + c*c` etc.

My helper function `abc(n)` computes the entries a/b/c of the n-th matrix power. For n=0, that's the identity matrix, so my a/b/c are 0/1/0 there. And in the end I, return the e-value (computed as e=b+d=a+b+c).

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow, maybe, with some sort of explanation. Full precision is just under 10 seconds on my machine. Modular is 30 microseconds on TIO: https://tio.run/##hVLhaoMwGPzfpzgKg2jdGtsfGzL3ImNIksZNmNHF9EcpfbM9w17Jfca0taN0H4jmvLvchbQ799GYdd9vdAkjrNgJI4q62TCToEWOtOCch@cxymagqYiK5xyrDFa7rTVIE0JewIdXTj88TSSQCRSZXBpjucQqGilF97UVVm@IJBBDeFROUEmo9KiaoIpQFRwkrVeD9sQUhZpgKngeMXnCfI87quFXw4Q6jJ2DLSZxFoN1RJI2OUmO80cSaMA1oiTKuc79eQcvGo9Gf3b632A3wtze46pEeZqaVg6BZqVtariq1qjqtrHOf8/KxqJAZWCFeddsHe6H43TUA4GNVVpbGcfK@f7iHqQ8jp@iV/6WpfyAPRsFFMHxKE65n@whLQ/4@e7mUd//Ag

Comment: In the course of getting that working, I discovered two interesting things about the `decimal` module. One is that its `%` operator does not handle negative arguments the same was as Python's. That's actually documented, but I missed it the first time. The other one is that it's about 50% slower since v3.10, at least using the Ubuntu packages.  I couldn't find any reference to that which leads me to suspect that it's a packaging problem, but who knows.

Comment: @rici Looking forward to the explanation. I noticed my matrix powers only really have five different values instead of nine, and giving them names `a` to `e` and writing down how squaring the matrix effects them I get expressions similar to yours.

Comment: yup, that's the key. The five values are in fact five consecutive Narayana numbers, and you can derive two of them from the other three. There's a very similar binary solution to Fibonacci. (Both Fibonacci and Narayana have closed form solutions, but those require floating point computations which make them unsuitable for this kind of programming puzzle.)

Comment: @rici I looked [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number#Numerical_values), I don't see our numbers there. What am I missing?

Comment: Different Narayana. You're off by about half a millennium. For this one, see [Narayana Pandita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_Pandita_(mathematician)). Search for cows in that page. It's OEIS A000930.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! I have been trying to understand the underlying math from a related link by @advocateofnone and have a question (http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/11/matrix-exponentiation.html). Referring to type 3 within this, my matrix is `[[1,0,1], [1,0,0],[0,1,0]]`. The answer seems to be in cell [0][0] then. Why is yours different?

Comment: @Wboy Their matrix B is upside down compared to mine. Their matrix A is affected accordingly.

Comment: @rici Ah, ok. And I see a golden ratio wasn't enough, there needed to be a "supergolden" one. Added my own version of your way now, also takes about 30 μs on TIO (but due to the low time I switched to better measuring, yours takes about 25 μs with that).

Comment: @rici And a [decimal-version](https://tio.run/##VdCxboMwEAbg3U9xSyTsugqhQ5NKDAQYK1WdulVgDhUJDDKmSp@engGZ5AYsf/4B3w1/9qfXL@fBzHNt@g4qVE1XtNB0Q28sCMZGtKrXFm82SLd1MKji9@Tr@@MzTyXkXXFbtjk9OGeswhrGvv3FQPM3BlROilL5vaumBg1xDOFOrgzayWgIJWTrXYITlxD6TCGhlKAgXj8IxyNE3J9WzuEJlBckKUkqLwlJJArhVIk9mS5eCuXSYs/niytRkaNA7xl5QpZ6uZLk8AzZY5MHiB57TCRc5fI/t8i7/Nb9FmB3NE5dsI6QJmxwnFpL769jPoVCnDkbTKNtsJ0dYOELXfCVBtiiDkZrtlPO@Tz/Aw) of it computing the full non-modulo number unsurprisingly takes about 19 seconds and confirms your 16,600,693 digits length.

Comment: @kellyBundy: Yes, I think I mentioned that in another comment. On my machine, it takes 9.6 seconds -- but only if I revert to Python 3.9. With Python 3.10 and Python 3.11, it takes about 15 seconds. You don't happen to understand that issue, do you?

Comment: @rici No, I don't know why it would become so much slower. If my PC weren't broken, I could try it on a machine with different Python versions as well. Will have to fix it first.

Comment: @rici [12.5 seconds on TIO](https://tio.run/##bZHBboMwDIbveQpfKpEsU2l3WDeJAwV2mzRNO@xWQTAaEgQUwtQ@PXMgoq00HxLl@x37l91f7E@nnw69mabKdC2UqOo2b6Bu@85YEIwNaFWnLZ5tkPi7N6ii9/j79PGZJRKyNj/Pz4wOzhkrsYKha34x0PyVAYUjeaECLaHTzeWE0VveDOhVF3UFGqIIwityYdCORkMoIV2cBTsuIVxzcgmFBAXRUh62W9jzVS0dhwdQK0EiBZFyJRmRvVCiJIoCbw0tVv81lK0wnv/nwlVV4topmXkhlOsmrv1S4jGxZCVHIhk8Qno/jA3s71vHEo5yrusueZPvTfkEdoP80L/MiLQYg8PYWCqwbGcXCnHgrDe1toHXNjDjF3L4TJNuUAeDNV7lnE/THw) by not computing more than necessary in the outermost call.

Comment: @Kelly: yeah, there are still cycles to save. But in principle, I think it demonstrates that you *can* compute the complete answer within the time-limit without a supercomputer. Unlike n.m, I don't see why that's bad. This whole `% 1000000007` thing is a crock which has zip-all to do with real programming issues. If you need a precise answer, you need a precise answer. If you only need a good approximation, there's a closed form which is *much* faster (in floating point). (Nanoseconds, I would guess.)

Comment: @rici Depends on what you consider "real programming". I consider the challenge as-is real programming, the modulo being a part of it. And in general I think it allows us to verify the correctness of an algorithm without having to spend an inconvenient amount of resources. Although I didn't think this through and don't intend to, since I simply like it the way it is.

Comment: I didn't say it isn't real programming; it's recreational programming, to be sure. I said it wasn't a real issue, meaning that it doesn't correspond to a real-world problem. As Joe Armstrong liked to point out, the categories of "problems programmers like to solve", "problems tech companies want solutions for" and "problems the majority of the world's population care about" are basically disjoint sets. Indeed, that was one of the first great pieces of advice I ever received, more than 50 years ago, from Joe Weizenbaum, and it's definitely worth thinking about.

Comment: @rici Earlier you said "If you need a precise answer, you need a precise answer". That sounds like you're acknowledging that that might be someone's real world problem/need. And then I'd say computing that modulo value *does* correspond to a real-world problem, namely to verifying a solution. Using a simpler one. Our solutions computing the precise answer are already somewhat complicated. And a major reason I trust my precise result (and thus my code) is that the modulo value is the same as what I computed with my much simpler solution from my other answer.

Comment: @Kelly I don't think it's necessary to compute N(10**8) to verify the algorithm. I compared mine with the 5000 entries in OEIS, which took milliseconds. There's a huge territory between what you can compute in milliseconds, and might be useful for something, and the point at which a modulo helps you know something, whatever that might be. (It doesn't tell you whether your arithmetic was efficient as it could be, for example :-) ) But whatever. I ain't gonna change your mind.

Comment: @rici It might not be "necessary", but I do find it useful. Just like checking those 5000 values is useful. In an earlier version of some solution I actually had a bug that didn't show up at first, when I was printing only the first few dozen values along with the correct values. 5000 is safer than a few dozen, but who knows, there could still be a bug that shows up only later, and 10^8 is significantly later. Both checks are valuable.

Answer (score 6):

Just write your recurrence using matrices (pardon my way of writing matrices, StackOverflow doesn't allow LaTeX).

```
[f(n)  ] = [1 0 1] [f(n-1)  ]
[f(n-1)] = [1 0 0] [f(n-2)  ]
[f(n-2)] = [0 1 0] [f(n-3)  ]
```

Now all you have to do is raise a 3x3 matrix (modulo fixed constant) to power n (or n-3 or something like that, depending on your "base case column vector", fill in the details), and then multiply it by a "base case column vector". This can be done in time O(logn).

PS: You may want to lookup [matrix exponentiation](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/67776).

Comment: Thank you so much for that link!! I have been trying to understand a simpler version in the comments of that link (http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/11/matrix-exponentiation.html) to anyone reading, it really helps

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple iterative O(n) time / O(1) space solution whose optimized version takes 6 seconds on a medium-fast machine (unoptimized takes 15 seconds there).

Unoptimized ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwDIbvfYr/IjRbD4qHTcFnkW7rdKBpiXWwp69tPYiBEPLl/5OELd49H/sgKU1uxss/VqeZzgo5nn7CBYd905zQoqvMZjLkHMukktkLrlgYYvn2M1exwWCqtBQDbduRsCuLq0ZcfAvDKhVk4ai/5zuiv7480BOl9AE)):

```
def solve(n):
    mod = 10**9 + 7
    a = b = c = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, (a+c) % mod
    return a

print(solve(7))
print(solve(10**8))
```

Optimized ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRC4IwFIXf9yvOi@BUUPEhC/wtsU0toTZZFvTr150WNmswxv3uPYezOz6ns9FVPVrn2q7HzVweXaz5gYHO1bRoUBZJskeK3cwEEUlX@c5MemNxxKBhhT6RGHmOqijeHn8myqC5mKbkGCDpkQiQ8kiyVRQ1PiJbJRugvsFPzGiTUmSQ2fwv/2SIRao4TX0MbDfdraZMbLSDnuJlVzvOg9pvq@bcuRc)):

```
def solve(n):
    mod = 10**9 + 7
    a = b = c = 1
    for _ in range(n // 300):
        for _ in range(100):
            a += c
            b += a
            c += b
        a %= mod
        b %= mod
        c %= mod
    for _ in range(n % 300):
        a, b, c = b, c, (a+c) % mod
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is on the right track and the bug is not related to your algorithm (Yay).

The problem is when you are performing operations on some big numbers you lose precision. Notice that you can apply the `mod 10 ** 9 + 7` along your code since addition is not affected by it. By doing so you keep all your numbers below a certain size and you will not have any floating point precision errors:

```py
import math

def memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n):
    if n not in dic:
        dic[n] = (memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n-3) + memoized_number_of_ways(dic, n-1)) % (math.pow(10,9) + 7)
    return dic[n]

def numberOfWays(n):
    memoize = {1:1,2:1,3:2}
    ans = memoized_number_of_ways(memoize,n)
    return ans
```

Note that for you to be able to answer the question for `n > 1000` you need to solve this recursion error problem.

Unfortunately even a very efficient solution (hint: you don't really need more than 3 items in your dict at any moment) will not solve the question for `n ~ 10 ** 9` under a second. And you will need to find another way - a great option is the second answer here :)

Comment: If they actually used `10 ** 9 + 7`, they wouldn't lose precision.

Comment: In Python, repeatedly adding integers *never* produces a floating point value, and never loses precision. It can take a lot of memory if the numbers are really big.

Comment: The limit for n is 10^8, not 10^9.